# Permalinks Won't Work

Tags: permalinks

Permanents won't work for some reason. I click on the radio button for option 3, and click save, but it reverts back to option 1. What's going on?

(It shouldn't be a FTP problem - it has localhost access to the database, and I can download plugins within Wordpress fine.)

Comment: Wordpress can write .htaccess? Is .htaccess allowed on your web host?

Comment: I'm quite sure they are allowed, but when I first got the host setup, there was no .htaccess, and there was no .htaccess created when I installed Wordpress.

Comment: Any error from wordpress when setting the permalink? A message giving you a warning that It cannot write the .htaccess? Follow the advice of Chip Bennet below

Comment: There's no error at all - it just reverts back to the first radio button, instead of the 3rd that I want.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost assuredly a file/directory permissions issue.

Try manually creating an empty `.htaccess` file, and [giving it **644* permissions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#.htaccess_permissions). Then see if WordPress can apply rewrite rules.